# Java Applet stopped working

Tags: java, networking, post, applet

I have a strange problem with my Java Applet. When I run it locally on my computer everything works fine but when I embed it into my website and go to the url it is not able to send a post request. To a server. A few weeks ago everything worked fine but from one day to another it is not working.

Do you have any idea what causes this problem?

Comment: Did you try to debug with firebug for example?

Comment: What is the content of the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml)?